# I am running into a No such file or directory error in bash, but it doesn't seem to be failing on a file

Tags: linux, bash

I have been running through my code for a while, and can't seem to find the reason this is failing because it is failing on line 10 apparently which is the if statement, but it is correctly finding the value of line.

```
#!/bin/bash
#a script that reads the largest number from a file

file="$1"
largest=""
while IFS= read -r line
do 
    if("$line" > "$largest")
    then
        "$largest"="$line"
    fi
done <"$file"
echo "$largest"
```

Comment: You're confusing redirection with inequality operators. try "greater-than", like `if [ x -gt y ]`.

Answer (score 5):

This is incorrect:

```
if("$line" > "$largest")
then
    "$largest"="$line"
fi
```

Change to:

```
if [ "$line" -gt "$largest" ]
then
    largest="$line"
fi
```

First, as the pointed out in the comment, `>` is a redirection operator, and bash is trying to run the "$line" command.  Parentheses are not test operators, the square brackets are.

Finally, the `"$largest"` is incorrect as the target of an assignment.  The `$` tells bash to provide the value of the variable, and we want to assign to `largest`, not to the VALUE of `largest`.

Comment: I suggest a bit of explanation in English: mention that `>`  is a redirection, and that `[`  is the `test`  standard command or builtin